# Мне кажется, что не хватает слова? Но "что чтобы" допустимо ли?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, стилистика

> И только кажется, что посетить какой-то музей достаточно одного раза.

*И только кажется, что, чтобы посетить какой-то музей, достаточно одного раза.*

Или:

*И только кажется, что для посещения какого-то музея достаточно одного раза.*

Всяк нехорошо. Для *посещения* действительно *достаточно одного раза*.

Никак не находится нужное слово, - изучения? ознакомления с?

Comment: Это только кажется, что получить представление о музее можно с одного посещения.

Comment: Спасибо, Саша! )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что нужно изменить грамматику и структуру предложения:

И  это только кажется, что **достаточно** посетить какой-то музей **один раз**. (Далее раскрывается мысль, почему это не так).

Другие варианты:

И только кажется, что **достаточно** посетить какой-то музей **один раз**, чтобы ознакомиться со всеми  его экспонатами.

И только кажется, что  **достаточно одного раза**, чтобы ознакомиться со всеми экспонатами музея.